# How do I split up a long long integer into 3 char sets?

Tags: c, string, long-integer

I have a long long integer variable which holds data like `20101201`

I need to split it up as `2010`, `12` and `01`.

Note: I need to do this in C program in my linux machine.

Comment: It's not clear whether you are using a long long integer (like you say) or a string (like the quotes and the tag suggests) to store that big number...

Comment: @Dave - I'm getting long long integer value and need to store it as three different strings

Comment: OK, I'll stick an answer in...

Answer (score 5):

You can divide by powers of 10 to get rid of numbers on the right:

```
(20101201/100/100)==2010
```

And the modulo of powers of 10 to get rid of numbers on the left:

```
(20101201%100)==01
```

And combine them to get the part in the middle:

```
(20101201/100)%100==12
```

Answer (score 1):

This one should be ok with longs, and puts the answers into strings.

```
long long int lWholeThing = 20101201LL;
long long int lDate = lWholeThing % 100LL;
lWholeThing /= 100LL;
long long int lMonth = lWholeThing % 100LL;
lWholeThing /= 100LL;
long long int lYear = lWholeThing;

char sDate [3];
char sMonth [3];
char sYear [5];

sprintf (sDate, "%02d", (int) lDate);
sprintf (sMonth, "%02d", (int) lMonth);
sprintf (sYear, "%d", (int) lYear);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the example you have given, you wanted to divide the number in to three sets:
Pass your input as an argument to the executable.

```
int main( int argc, char **argv)
{

 long long int x;

 x=atoll(argv[1]);

 printf("\n %d", x%100);
 x=x/100;

 printf("\n %d", x%100);
 x=x/100;
 printf("\n %d", x);

}
```

Comment: Same problem..atoi can't handle long long int and the result has not been converted to string.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // for itoa() call -- built in to convert integer to string
#include <stdio.h>  // for printf() call

int main() {
    int num = 123;
    char buf[5];

    // convert 123 to string [buf]
    itoa(num, buf, 10);

    // print our string
    printf("%s\n", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Then you can just complete your program by using index to split the numbers into different strings.